# how can I get bolt data source?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm new to storm environment and I have a question! I have 2 spouts (spoutA and spoutB) that emits data to a bolt (bolt1). I defined this bolt in this way:

```
builder.setBolt("bolt1", bolt1).shuffleGrouping("spoutA").shuffleGrouping("spoutB");
```

Is there a way in bolt1 to know for every tuple received what is its source (spoutA or spoutB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [official doc page](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Tutorial.html)

> If you implement a bolt that subscribes to multiple input sources, you can find out which component the Tuple came from by using the **Tuple#getSourceComponent** method